# Hudson does not want to start in Opensuse anymore. Empty pid file

Tags: linux, hudson, opensuse, init.d

I installed using the hudson.rpm as specified on the site provided. I also installed ant after starting hudson, for some reason when i try to run

> /etc/init.d/hudson start

it just fails saying

> Starting Hudson startproc: Empty pid
>   file /var/run/hudson.pid for
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

Sorry if this is a stupid question, any help will by much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is related to the [Jenkins issue 5020](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5020) then have a look on the [committed patch](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/f80cf8b0ca02b959dece845e2636a278dcf5202a). Resolved the issue for me.